# API requests works in chrome, but doesn't work with python requests module

Tags: python, http, google-api, google-geocoding-api

I requested about 40,000 times to google's geocode api, and almost every requests were successful, but only few requests didn't work.(responded with ZERO_RESULT)

I thought it would be a encoding problem, but when I insert parsed url in chrome, it responded results. But still, when I tried it with python requests with exactly same url, it responded ZERO_RESULTS(which means literally no results)

this is what I got

```py
get_geodata_debug("650 FROM ROAD SOUTH LOBBY, 4TH FLOOR PARAMUS NJ 07652")
```

I erased my api key.

```
raw address = 650 FROM ROAD SOUTH LOBBY, 4TH FLOOR PARAMUS NJ 07652
parsed address = 650+FROM+ROAD+SOUTH+LOBBY%2C+4TH+FLOOR+PARAMUS+NJ+07652
url = https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=MYAPIKEY&address=650+FROM+ROAD+SOUTH+LOBBY%2C+4TH+FLOOR+PARAMUS+NJ+07652
{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

```py
def get_geodata_debug(address):
    _results_status = ""
    _results_length = 0
    _location ={}
    print("raw address = "+address)
    address = parse.quote_plus(str(address))
    print("parsed address = "+address)
    params = "key=%s&address=%s"%(key,address)
    url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?%s'%(params)
    print("url = "+url)
    response = requests.get(url)
    print(response.text)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        response_json = response.json()
        _results_status = response_json["status"]


        if _results_status == 'OK':
            _results_length = len(response_json["results"])

            _location = response_json["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]

    return response.status_code, _results_status, _results_length, _location
```

I want same results in both python and chrome

Comment: I can't find address "650 FROM ROAD SOUTH LOBBY, 4TH FLOOR PARAMUS NJ 07652" in Google Maps either which also returns zero results, are you sure this is a valid address?